# How to get a sequence of 5 numbers from an array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, vector

I want to get a sequence of 5 numbers from an array.
For example :

```
int arr1[] = {3,88,99,5,4,6,22,32,7,45}; // array where there is the sequence 3,4,5,6,7
Vector<Integer> myVec = new Vector<Integer>(); // vector wehre to save the sequence
```

Now what do I have to do to get the sequence from that array?
I have a code here but it does not work properly:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr1.length -1; i++) {

    int a = arr1[i];
    int b = arr1[i+1];
    int c = b - a;

    if(c == 1) {
        myvec.add(arr1[i]);
    }
}
```

How should I change my code to solve this?

Comment: use Arrays.sort() then apply your logic

Comment: Not sure what it is you want to acheive

Comment: I want to put the sequence "3,4,5,6,7" from arr1 in myvec.

Comment: Do you know those "3,4,5,6,7" in advance or do you want any series of consecutive numbers ?
Any numbers ?
Any serie size ?

Comment: this was just an example. I need every sequence of 5 consecutive numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program will print all the sequence in the array **WITHOUT SORTING THE ARRAY**. You could select the list with size.. Say if you want match 5 sequence get the list with size 5. Hope this help. (Modify as per your need.)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Sequence {

    private static int arr1[] = { 3, 88, 99, 5, 4, 6, 22, 32, 7, 45 };

    private static int findNextInSequence(int start) {
        int next = -1;

        for(int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
            if((start - arr1[i]) == -1){
                next = arr1[i];
            }
        }

        return next;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {

            List<Integer> sequence = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            int nextSequence = arr1[i];
            do{
                sequence.add(nextSequence);
                nextSequence = findNextInSequence(nextSequence);
            } while(nextSequence != -1);

            System.out.println(sequence);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code checks the difference between two successive values from arr1 array. Because it is not sorted, it works like this:

```
88-3 !=1 (value not added)
99-88 !=1 (value not added)
5-99 !=1 (value not added)
...
45-7 !=1 (value not added).
```

You have to ensure that values in your array are sorted first. Use Arrays.sort() and apply the method on sorted array. This should add values: 3,4,5,6, but it WON'T add 7 (because it'll be your arr[i+1] value at the time of loop execution.

```
4-3 ==1 (value added)
5-4 ==1 (value added)
6-5 ==1 (value added)
7-6 ==1 (value added, but it is only number 6 that is added!)
```

Comment: is there any other possibility without using Arrays.sort()?

Comment: You can write your own sort method or you can compare every number with each other.

Comment: writing own method will not help because in unsorted array it will find "3" then skip "5" and then add "4". You will not be able to go back to "5". If you don't want to sort the array you can try using two loops one inside another but it is a vary bad practice.

Comment: not in his case because he will skip some numbers due to this condition:
   int c = b - a;

    if(c == 1)

Answer (score 0):

You should count successive count upto 5 and put the result into `ArrayList` instead of `Vector`. Because, `ArrayList` is more efficient than `Vector`. Try,

```
 int arr1[] = {3, 88, 99, 5, 4, 6, 22, 32, 7, 45, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
 List<Integer> myVec = new ArrayList<>();

 Arrays.sort(arr1);

    int count = 0;
    int lastValue = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length - 1; i++) {
        if (arr1[i + 1] - arr1[i] == 1) {
            count++;
            System.out.println(arr1[i]);
            lastValue = arr1[i + 1];
        } else {
            System.out.println(count);
            if (count >= 4) {
                for (int j = 0; j <= count; j++) {
                    myVec.add(lastValue - 4 + j);
                }
            }
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(myVec);
```